# How can i get Apple HealthKit data if iphone is crashed or permanently dead?

Tags: iphone, health.app, health-kit

What if i does not backup my Apple healthkit data, And one day my iphone is crashed or permanently dead. So how can i get my old HealthKit data?
Is any other option from where can i get my old HealthKit data? Or Backup is compulsory to get old Data?

Comment: Without a backup you are likely out of luck. I have heard of data recovery companies that can get data off of phones, but those are **expensive** and no guarantee they will be able to get what you need. Turn on iCloud backup.

Answer (score 3):

As with any computer: If you want to be sure your data survives crashes, device losses etc, make a backup (or ideally several).